# Get and filter multiple classes inside of iqueryable object

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, iqueryable

I can't figure out how to get this query to work!
I need to create iquerialble list of Orders and select only the orders which have StateId from class OrderState equal to desired number
  
Here are my model classes!

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual ICollection<OrderState> OrderState { get; set; }       
}

public class OrderState
{
    public int OrderStateId {get;set;}
    public int OrderId{get;set;}
    public int StateId{get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<State> State { get; set; }       
}

public partial class State
{
    public int StateId{get;set;}
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

And here is my code

```
var query = _context.Set<Database.Order>().AsQueryable();

if (search.UserId!= 0)
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.UserId == search.UserId);
}

if (search.OrderId!=0)
{
query = query.Where(x => x.OrderId == search.OrderId);
}

if(search.StateId!=0)
{
//query =get every Order where StateId from Orderstate == search.StateId
}

var entities = query.ToList(); 
return _mapper.Map<List<Model.Order>>(entities);
```

Any help is appreciated!!
Thanks for trying to help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the orderstate list is a history of states the order has been in? It would perhaps be more useful if the orderstate table had more columns, like the datetime the order transitioned to that state, by the way.. Also the orderstate collection in Order should be called OrderStates plural, because it is a collection. Doing so makes code more readable/self describing; plurals essentially say "you can call LINQ stuff on me"

Anyway, you probably want "where any of the states is X"

```
if(search.StateId!=0)
{
    query = query.Where(o => o.OrderStates.Any(os => os.StateId == search.StateId));
}
```

On the DB this will translate to something like `FROM Orders o WHERE EXISTS(SELECT null FROM OrderStates os WHERE os.Id = o.Id AND os.StateId = @p1)`